# Scala replace element pairs in list

Tags: scala

I have a list of playing cards defined by:

```
case class Card(suit : String, value : String)
```

Example value ("clubs", "7") is suit = clubs and value = 7. A list contains a pair of cards when both suits of the same color and the same value are in the list. Now I want to have a function that accepts a list of cards and replaces all card pairs with the Card("red", value) or Card("black", value) if the pair is red or black respectively.

Is there a way to write this using the list operators? Or what would be the Scala-way to do this? I do not have much experience using Scala.

An example:

```
input: [("clubs", "5"), ("hearts", "2"), ("spades", "5") ]
output: [("black", "5"), ("hearts", "2")]
```

Comment: I don't really understand. You want to go from a `List[Card]` to `List[CardColor]` with `case class CardColor(color: String, value: String)` or something?

Comment: I guess I don't understand this part of the questions: `A list contains a pair of cards when both suits of the same color and the same value are in the list.` Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what issues you are having?

Comment: @mfirry ("clubs", "5") and ("spades", "5") would form a pair. And no I want to go from List[Card] to a List[Card], the types remain the same, only the string values change. It is a toy example, I just want to know how something like this would be handled in Scala, possibly using list operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

(I added some helpers to the `Card` class to make this clearer)

```
case class Card(suit: String, value: String) {
  def isRed = suit == "hearts" || suit == "diamonds"
  def colourName = if (isRed) "red" else "black"
}

def makePairs(cards: List[Card]): List[Card] =
  cards.groupBy(_.value).values.map {
    case a :: _ :: Nil => Card(a.colourName, a.value)
    case a :: Nil => a
  }.toList

val (red, black) = cards.partition(_.isRed)

makePairs(red) ++ makePairs(black)
```

This works by splitting the cards into red and black sets, grouping them by `value`, and then converting pairs of the same `value` into the appropriate "red" or "black" card.

This will fail badly on invalid data, so do add some error checking.